# How do I know if a React library uses cookies?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-cookie, react-cookie-consent

In my React app I'm not currently using cookies.  Therefore I don't think I need to show a 'Cookie Settings' banner.  But it occurred to me that maybe some of the npm libraries I'm using, or something built in to React itself, might be using cookies - is that possible and if so, is there a way to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually cookies are involved when there is some sort of "memory" that the application needs to have when communicating with a server.
If the library is client only usually it does not use coookies. To check your cookies you can just open an anonymous window on your browser and point to your application running on localhost. If you then open the dev tools (F12 on Chrome and Firefox) you can check check in the "Application" (Chrome) or "Storage" (Firefox) tab if there are some cookies that you haven't set yourself.